# What is the idea/algorithm behind the Tab close animation on Safari on iPad?

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

I'm looking to recreate the (collapse into a point) safari.app tab close animation. Can some animation gurus chime in on some algorithms/pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The tab close animation in Safari on iPad, and the mail deletion animation in Mail on iPhone use Core Animation filters. These filters are private Apple, and available for you unless you use private API:s.

Your best solution is to request the filter as a public API at http://bugreport.apple.com

Your second option available to you today is to recreate the animation using a mesh of OpenGL triangles.